# Data specific print as PSPP variable view in R

Tags: r

I have a .sav file. I want to print out the data properly as PSPP variable view in R.

[image: PSPP variable view]

Succeeded to print the type of data, but not the other specific sg.: width, label, value label,...

I using following command to read data:

```
library(foreign)
library(memisc)
data <- read.spss("Database.sav", use.value.labels = FALSE,
                                      max.value.labels = 100)
x = do.call(rbind,data)
```

Comment: Those elements are SPSS-specific details about variable types. They don't exist in the same form in R. You have variable classes (numeric, integer, character, etc.) but they don't map directly the types available in SPSS. Width is also irrelevant in R. I believe the variable labels will be preserved as attributes attached to your `data` object.

Comment: Ok, How to print the value data labels?

Answer (score 2):

Please check the following command for variable and value labels read from SPSS in R. Hope this will work...

```
library(foreign)
## Read SPSS data
data<-read.spss("Database.sav",use.value.labels=FALSE,to.data.frame=FALSE)
data_frame<-as.data.frame(data)
dim(data_frame)
# Variable Labels...
variable_labels <- attr(data, "variable.labels")
variable_labels
# Value Labels...
value_labels<-attr(data,"label.table")
value_labels
```